# Error while change in Design in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, casting, code-generation, desktop-application

I am developing window application in vb.net. In that i am using Umisoft.UI controls in my application. Now i am changing something in design. but i cant able to save it and following error comes.

[image: Error]

I don't know why this error comes? and it is coming every time while saving or change in design.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem? give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As this is happening at design time, it is likely that you have a custom control which requires a parameter or other value which does not have a default or is using an expression which results in a exception.

When designing a control in visual studio, it is rendered, but if the control requires a property to be set before it can be rendered, it will result in an error if that property does not have a default or it is invalid.

`CodePrimitiveExpression` represents a primitive data type value and probably your custom control is using an expression to cast to a data type (`CodeCastExpression`) which is generating this issue.